# What does "feel these things" in this video clip mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Below is a part of the transcript from an animated movie "Big Hero 6":
(Video clip link: https://youtu.be/PTcLZLKPOtM?t=26)
(Transcript link: https://www.quotes.net/mquote/978305)

Cass: Hiro? You home, sweetie?
Hiro: Uh, that's right.
Cass: I thought I heard you. Hi.
Hiro: [casually] H-Hey, Aunt Cass.
Cass: Oh, look at my little college man. Oh, I can't wait to hear all about it! Oh, and wings are almost ready.
Baymax: Weeee!
Hiro: [whispers] Will you be quiet!
Cass: Yeah, weeee! Weeooh! [as Hiro desperately tries to push Baymax upstairs, unseen] All right, get ready to have your face melted! You are gonna **feel these things** tomorrow, you know what I'm saying? Okay, sit down, tell me everything. [She turns around and Hiro's not there]

Could you explain the meaning of "feel these things" at the end of the above transcript?
[image]

Comment: Spicy chicken wings... you are going to feel them ('these things') on the toilet tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Feel** means "sense", or "perceive", as it normally does.

**These things** are the chicken wings she's cooking.  She has just said, "Wings are almost ready", so that should be a clue about the context.

[Chicken wings are often spicy.](https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/663/meat-and-poultry/chicken/chicken-wings/)  So Hiro will still be perceiving them the next day.

(I don't think it necessarily means "on the toilet", as Michael Harvey says.  It might, but it could also mean Hiro will still be tasting them tomorrow, or just a more metaphorical exaggeration "These are so powerful you will still be tasting them tomorrow.")

Comment: But they say 'feeling', which is not the same as 'tasting'.